# I want to save a variable that is constantly going to be changing the value thats stored in it. I want to save each value. How would I do that?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot that constantly stores a message sent by the user. I want to save these message somewhere, and then when the bot is called, I want to randomly send one of the messages I've saved. Or show them a list of all the messages i've saved.

Here is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def quote(ctx,user:discord.Member,*,message):
    color=discord.Color(value=0x9C2A00)
    async for messages in ctx.channel.history(limit=1):
        pass
    em=discord.Embed(color=color,title=message,description=f'-{user}, [original](https://discordapp.com/channels/{messages.guild.id}/{messages.channel.id}/{messages.id})')
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

I want to keep saving the 'em' variable. Or i guess more specifically the title and description of the em variable.

I tried storing the variable `em` in a list and that worked! However, it only stored the last value of `em`. I want to store each value of `em`.
What I did was as follows:

```
em=#the code
em_list=[]
em_list.append(em)
```

However, each time a new value is given to 'em' the old one in the list is overwritten with the new value. I want to store each value, not just the latest one.

Comment: You said it yourself: a list.  If you do not know how to accumulate a sequence of values in a list, then you need to work through a tutorial on the topic.

Comment: @Prune Hey! Yes storing the variable em in a list worked! The only problem is that everytime a new value is given to em the old one is overwritten. I want to store all the values given to em. Do you know how i could do that? this is my code right now: https://prnt.sc/umm4q6

Comment: As you already said, use a list.  Don't overwrite your scalar variable; append to a list.  If you have a coding problem, then supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Off-site links are not acceptable here.  Critical information goes into your question, not a comment.

Comment: Sorry!! I did not know off-site links were not allowed. Im new to programming and i dont quite understand what you mean by 'Don't overwrite your scalar variable; append to a list.' I've edited my question to include what you said about critical information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, please refer to any tutorial on list handling.  In particular

```
# Do this once: initialize your list
em_list=[]
...

# In your code that executes multiple time:

    em=#the code
    em_list.append(copy(em))

# hHen that is all done ...
for em in em_list:
    # Do whatever you want with each element in the list
    print(em)
```

Comment: Hey! The problem with this is that once em is updated all references point to the new value.

Comment: The long-term cause of this is that you neglected to give us an appropriate example in your post.  You left `em` as an in-place, mutable variable (look up the `mutable` concept).  To fix this, use the `copy` update I just put in.  You will likely have to import the function.

Comment: Thank you! Im really sorry im quite new to programming. However I found a solution that was inspired by what you said. I realized that every time the command was run, the 'em_list' was reset to an empty list. That was the problem. So what i did was I moved the list to the very top of the code and made it a global variable! Thank you! Im really sorry this was such a pain for me to explain. Sorry!!

Comment: Look at the code I posted: I *told* you to initialize only once, and to append only in the repeated part.  :-)

Comment: Global variables are generally *not* a good idea.  Instead, you should make it some appropriate function parameter, or refactor your code so that all of the updating comes within a single function.

Comment: dude im so sorry lol my brain likes to toggle off from time to time!! Thank you though!! Ive gotten the command to work near perfectly since then!!

Answer (score 1):

There are two convenient ways to store the data: list or dictionary.

In case it is a key:value pair of data that you are storing, you will be better off with a dictionary. In a dictionary, the key is what points to the value. Each value has a key with which it can be located within a dictionary. So, in case you want to store the data as a key-value pair, where the key can be the 'user' name or the 'message' name, while the value can be the 'em' variable.

```
em_dict = {}
em_dict[message] = em
# 'em' can then be used to store another item, and that item can be stored in
# the em_dict with a different message or user key
```

Whereas if you simply want to store only the 'em's content, irrespective of which 'user' or 'message' title it corresponds to, you can simply create a list of all the variables that 'em' stores temporarily:

```
em_list = []
em_list.append(em)
# Then change the value of em and store it using the list's append() method.
```

Both the dictionary and the list can be used to store the 'em' values using a for loop

Comment: Thank you! But everytime i append em into the list, wont it overwrite the first one? because the variable name is still the same? Or even if it doesnt overwrite it, each em will just equal the same thing?

Comment: Ohh! I just understood what you meant! However there still is a problem with this way of storing the data. I have 3 pieces of information that I want to save; I want to save the username of who sent the message, i want to save what the message was, and then also the link to the message. However with a dictionary i can only store one of those values.

Comment: Hey again! Im really really sorry to keep disturbing you. I tried the list method you suggested and it worked!! Only problem is that everytime a new 'em' is appended into the list the old one is overwritten. Is there anyway to fix that? Here is my code so far: https://prnt.sc/umltuu

Comment: An off-site link to your code is useless here: keep in mind the purpose of the site.

Comment: On a note on dictionaries, @sanguine, you can store the values as a nested dictionary. You might need to look up a few examples to get a hang of it, but yes, it's worth a shot.

Comment: Okay! Thank you man!!! @HarryS I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the variable. Otherwise every time it is updated all its references will point to the new value.

```
em_list = []
# when em updates:
em2 = em
em_list.append(em2)
# when em updates again:
em3 = em
em_list.append(em3)
```

The better way to do it is to not store the values in a variable at all. You can just append them to a list directly, without a name:

```
em_list = []
em_list.append(1)
em_list.append(2)
em_list.append(3)
```

Comment: Thank you!!! How can I check when em is updated and how do i keep creating new variables and saving them? You said i could just append them directly, but i dont understand how? doesnt em_list.append(3) just append the number 3? Thankyou!!

Comment: There isn't an easy way to be alerted when a variable changes. You can have a function that stores the old value and checks for equivalence on a loop... but really this should be a warning sign to you that there may be a better way of accomplishing what you're trying to do.